# python service return error OSError: screen grab failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

i write a window service with python that when google chrome is running take screen capture from window and save avi file to drive c:/

when run program without service it's work fine and return no error

but when run in service return error below in event viewer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\taher\Desktop\auto record\index.py", line 66, in SvcDoRun
    self.main()
  File "C:\Users\taher\Desktop\auto record\index.py", line 113, in main
    self.record()
  File "C:\Users\taher\Desktop\auto record\index.py", line 75, in record
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
  File "C:\Users\taher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 144, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\taher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 456, in _screenshot_win32
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
  File "C:\Users\taher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 43, in grab
    offset, size, data = Image.core.grabscreen_win32(
OSError: screen grab failed
```

i used `psutil` to find `chrome.exe`

also use `opencv` to capture window

here my code:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket

import psutil 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import os
import datetime

import sys
import traceback

  

# Specify resolution



# Create an Empty window
#cv2.namedWindow("Live", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
  
# Resize this window
#cv2.resizeWindow("Live", 480, 270)
  

# Release the Video writer

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Taher22_record"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Taher22_record"
    resolution = (1920, 1080)
    shouldInit = False
    # Specify video codec
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
    
    # Specify name of Output file
    filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")+'.avi'
    
    # Specify frames rate. We can choose any 
    # value and experiment with it
    fps = 16.0
    Xs = [0,8,6,10,8,4,2,0]
    Ys = [0,2,4,8,10,6,8,0]  
    
    # Creating a VideoWriter object

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)        
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)


    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                          (self._svc_name_,''))
        try:
            self.main()
        except:
            servicemanager.LogErrorMsg(traceback.format_exc()) # if error print it to event log
            os._exit(-1)

    def record(self):
        

        mouseX,mouseY = pyautogui.position()
        img = pyautogui.screenshot()
        # Convert the screenshot to a numpy array
        frame = np.array(img)
    
        # Convert it from BGR(Blue, Green, Red) to
        # RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        
        Xthis = [4*x+mouseX for x in self.Xs]
        Ythis = [4*y+mouseY for y in self.Ys]
        points = list(zip(Xthis,Ythis))
        points = np.array(points, 'int32')
        cv2.fillPoly(frame,[points],color=[255,255,255])
        # Write it to the output file
        self.out.write(frame)


    def check_run(self,program):
        found = False
        for p in psutil.process_iter():
            if(p.name()==program):
                found=True
                break
        return found


    def main(self):
        rc = None
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    
            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)

        # Take screenshot using PyAutoGUI
            if(self.check_run('chrome.exe')):
                if(self.shouldInit == False):
                    self.shouldInit = True
                    self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('C:/css',self.filename), self.codec, self.fps, self.resolution)
                    self.out.set(4, 720)
                self.record()
            else:
                self.out.release()
                self.filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")+'.avi'
                self.shouldInit = False
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
    #app = AppServerSvc([])
    #app.main()
    #for p in psutil.process_iter(): 
    #    print(p.name()=='chrome.exe')
```

Comment: I'm not sure but service (for security reason) may not have access to your screen because someone could write virus which makes screenshots to steal your password to bank account.